# Demographics of Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, statistics, demographics

I found the demographics for stack overflow on [quantcast](http://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com), just thought I would share them in case there is anyone else besides me interested in this kind of trivia. :)

**Gender**

- 78% male
- 22% female

**Age**

- 35% 18-34
- 30% 35-49
- 25% 50+
- 8% 13-17
- 1% 3-12

**Race**

- 68% Caucasian
- 19% Asian
- 9% African American
- 3% Hispanic
- 2% Other

**Kids**

- 79% No Kids 0-17
- 21% Has Kids 0-17

**Income**

- 29% $100k+
- 27% $0-30k
- 24% $30-60k
- 20% $60-100k

**Education**

- 43% College
- 34% No College
- 23% Grad School

**Visited from**

- 60% Home
- 39% Work

Comment: This is presumably to be taken with a grain of salt, as it is not based on actual data, but projections, and for the U.S. only. It also contains this gem: `The typical visitor reads experts-exchange.com, buys from ibm.com, and frequents metafilter.com` :) Still, very, very interesting reading!

Comment: How can it possibly figure out all that data?

Comment: See: [What can StackOverflow do to persuade female programmers to participate more?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30411/what-can-stackoverflow-do-to-persuade-female-programmers-to-participate-more) for a discussion of Quantcast accuracy...

Comment: can we do this for Super User? I'm a big fan!

Answer (score 7):

**Favourite thing on SE sites**

- 24% Drawing freehand circles
- 22% Unicorn avatars
- 17% Waffles
- 14% Jon Skeet
- 11% Friday in Iceland
- -6% Down voting anything that mentions down votes
- 4% Asking questions on the wrong site

Comment: By posting this, your second-last stat may be increasing very soon.

Answer (score 3):

> **Visited from**
>
> - 60% Home
> - 39% Work

<*cough*> bullsh** <*cough*>

Comment: Maybe 50% of us work from home

Answer (score 1):

The income statistic is a pretty interesting cause it seems like it is high-level professionals or students who mostly use the site

Comment: Yeh, but the difference is so small that statistically it seems like it's pretty even.

Comment: @Lance: you have to consider that something like less than 5% of the population earns $100k+, so the "difference" is huge.

Comment: I agree the difference is small too.  Just interesting in the disparity in income between the top two percentages